# Custom post type: creating a page template with the same slug

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm currently working on a custom post type and want to be able to edit the archive page from Wordpress with a page template. So I created the CPT called 'cars' and created a page template with template name: 'Cars overview'. Next i create a page inside WordPress and choose the template page 'Cars overview' and gave it the URL: mywebsite.com/cars/

Now the problem is that the slug 'mywebsite.com/cars/' is already in use by the custom post type itself causing the page to load the custom post type loop instead of the page template loop. So I can't edit the title, content etc inside WordPress. I could change the url of the page, but i want to be able to control the overview page in WordPress.

Long story short: How can I create a page template that is using the same URL as the custom post type archive page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to set the custom post types `has_archive` augment to `false` e.g. `'has_archive' => false`. This will disable the default archive page for that post type. You would then need to code your own custom loop in your custom template (Pagination can be tricky, but there are plenty of resources on how to implement it on a custom loop). That is as much help as I am willing to give, because it is a very general question. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution, simply disable the archive where you create your custom post type:

```
register_post_type("cars", array("has_archive" => false));
```

Another approach rather then disabling the archiving and adding another page to show the cars. Changing the archive template used by your theme might be a better option.

First step is to find the template currently in use by your theme, copy it to your plugin file and you can change the template file to whatever you like. [You can find more information about it here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates)

The only thing you need to do is point WordPress to the right direction:

```
add_filter("archive_template", "archive_template");
function archive_template($archive_template) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "cars")
    {
        $archive_template = "path/to/your/template.php";
    }

    return $archive_template;
}
```

Disabling the archive and creating one manually seems a bit strange to me. And I always replace the archive page and sometimes single page from our theme (usually the7).